# Angular2-form: Is it possible to include child input to parent NgForm valuechanges?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Angular version: v4.2.x

I'm having a form containing a child component:

**parent.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <form #myForm="ngForm">
          <child-component [parentForm]="myForm" [inputName]="'myName'"></child-component>
        </form>
     `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("myForm") myForm: NgForm;
}
```

**child.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
   template: `
      <input [name]="inputName" [(ngModel)]="petName"></input>
    `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input("parentForm") parentForm: NgForm;
   @Input("inputName") inputName: string;
   petName: string;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.parentForm.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(changes));
      });
   }
}
```

When typing in the child input field, I cannot see any change in the console. But if I move the same code from child to parent and get rid of child component, the changes are output in the console when typing.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Your child component to implement `ControlValueAccessor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding `ngModel` directive to parent `NgForm` manually:

**child.component.html**

```html
<input [name]="inputName" #model="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="petName">
```

**child.component.ts**

```typescript
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  @ViewChild("model") ngModel: NgModel;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parentForm.addControl(this.ngModel); // <== add this
    this.parentForm.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(changes));
    });
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/wA01VLfPTIBANBJBFiGe?p=preview)**